# How to make a background 20% transparent on Android

Tags: android, transparency, textview

How do I make the background of a `Textview` about 20% transparent (not fully transparent), where there is a color in the background (i.e. white)?

Comment: Must look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors

Answer (score 1113, accepted):

Make the color have 80% in the alpha channel. For example, for red use `#CCFF0000`:

```
<TextView
   ...
   android:background="#CCFF0000" />
```

In the example, `CC` is the hexadecimal number for `255 * 0.8 = 204`. Note that the first two hexadecimal digits are for the alpha channel. The format is `#AARRGGBB`, where `AA` is the alpha channel, `RR` is the red channel, `GG` is the green channel and `BB` is the blue channel.

I'm assuming that 20% transparent means 80% opaque. If you meant the other way, instead of `CC` use `33` which is the hexadecimal for `255 * 0.2 = 51`.

In order to calculate the proper value for an alpha transparency value you can follow this procedure:

1. Given a transparency percentage, for example 20%, you know the opaque percentage value is 80% (this is `100-20=80`)
2. The range for the alpha channel is 8 bits (`2^8=256`), meaning the range goes from 0 to 255.
3. Project the opaque percentage into the alpha range, that is, multiply the range (255) by the percentage. In this example `255 * 0.8 = 204`. Round to the nearest integer if needed.
4. Convert the value obtained in 3., which is in base 10, to hexadecimal (base 16). You can use Google for this or any calculator. Using Google, type "204 to hexa" and it will give you the hexadecimal value. In this case it is `0xCC`.
5. Prepend the value obtained in 4. to the desired color. For example, for red, which is `FF0000`, you will have `CCFF0000`.

You can take a look at the [Android documentation for colors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color).

Comment: For _white_ color with transparency, according to the question, use `android:background="#CCFFFFFF"`.

Comment: How to apply this rule for a background with image?

Answer (score 1717):

Use the below code for black:

```
<color name="black">#000000</color>
```

Now if I want to use opacity then you can use the below code:

```
 <color name="black">#99000000</color> <!-- 99 is for alpha and others pairs zero's are for R G B -->
```

And below for opacity code: and [**all opacity level here**](https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4)

#### Hex Opacity Values

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

If you always to forget what code for transparency then you must have to see below link and no worry about to remember anything regarding transparent code :-

https://github.com/duggu-hcd/TransparentColorCode

```
textviewHeader.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(ColorTransparentUtils.transparentColor(R.color.border_color,10)));
```

Comment: It should be noted that the values are transparency values, not opacity values.

Answer (score 183):

You can manage color opacity changing the first 2 characters in the color definition:

#**99**000000

```
100% — FF
99% — FC
98% — FA
97% — F7
96% — F5
95% — F2
94% — F0
93% — ED
92% — EB
91% — E8

90% — E6
89% — E3
88% — E0
87% — DE
86% — DB
85% — D9
84% — D6
83% — D4
82% — D1
81% — CF

80% — CC
79% — C9
78% — C7
77% — C4
76% — C2
75% — BF
74% — BD
73% — BA
72% — B8
71% — B5

70% — B3
69% — B0
68% — AD
67% — AB
66% — A8
65% — A6
64% — A3
63% — A1
62% — 9E
61% — 9C

60% — 99
59% — 96
58% — 94
57% — 91
56% — 8F
55% — 8C
54% — 8A
53% — 87
52% — 85
51% — 82

50% — 80
49% — 7D
48% — 7A
47% — 78
46% — 75
45% — 73
44% — 70
43% — 6E
42% — 6B
41% — 69

40% — 66
39% — 63
38% — 61
37% — 5E
36% — 5C
35% — 59
34% — 57
33% — 54
32% — 52
31% — 4F

30% — 4D
29% — 4A
28% — 47
27% — 45
26% — 42
25% — 40
24% — 3D
23% — 3B
22% — 38
21% — 36

20% — 33
19% — 30
18% — 2E
17% — 2B
16% — 29
15% — 26
14% — 24
13% — 21
12% — 1F
11% — 1C

10% — 1A
9% — 17
8% — 14
7% — 12
6% — 0F
5% — 0D
4% — 0A
3% — 08
2% — 05
1% — 03
0% — 00
```

Comment: What does this add to the existing answers?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I guess this answer is useful when you need more fine grained transparency like 87% or 54%, like the ones mentioned in https://material.google.com/style/color.html#color-color-schemes

Comment: Yes, yesterday I had the need to manage a 13% alpha and I decided to add my search result to this useful thread.

Comment: What if I wanted to make a LinearLayout complete transparent without any color?

Comment: All views are transparent by default, you can use programmatically mLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
or 
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
in your xml if you have to force it for some reasons
(obviously this color is not inherited by the child views)

Answer (score 116):

Use a color with an alpha value like `#33------`, and set it as background of your editText using the XML attribute `android:background=" "`.

1. 0% (transparent) -> #00 in hex
2. 20% -> #33
3. 50% -> #80
4. 75% -> #C0
5. 100% (opaque) -> #FF

**255 * 0.2 = 51 → in hex 33**

Answer (score 115):

You can try to do something like:

```
textView.getBackground().setAlpha(51);
```

Here you can set the opacity between 0 (fully transparent) to 255 (completely opaque). The 51 is exactly the 20% you  want.

Comment: @koti, because your `textView` variable is `null`.

Comment: nice elegant solution.  I'm able to apply this to a list item background when I'm selecting it - so I get some color, but it doesn't compete with the item text.. Very cool, thanks!

Comment: setAlpha(int) is deprecated in favor of setAlpha(float) where 0 is fully transparent and 1 is fully opaque myImage.setAlpha(0.5f);

Comment: @polmabri, not really. `myImage.setAlpha(0.5f);` applies the alpha to the View itself but what I show in my answer is being applied to the View's background drawable.

Comment: This may cause graphic bugs! Use with caution and lots of testing.

Comment: When used on a button, I like that this doesn't kill the 'glow' material design effect when you press and hold. I've found changing anything else like color or background resource kills this effect. An elegant programmatic solution.

Answer (score 84):

> We can make transparent in dis way also.

White color code - FFFFFF

**20% white** - #**33**FFFFFF

**20% — 33**

**70% white** - #**B3**FFFFFF

**70% — B3**

All teh hex value from **100% to 0%**

```
**100% —** **FF**,
99% — FC,
98% — FA,
97% — F7,
96% — F5,
95% — F2,
94% — F0,
93% — ED,
92% — EB,
91% — E8,
**90% —** **E6**,
89% — E3,
88% — E0,
87% — DE,
86% — DB,
85% — D9,
**84% —** **D6**,
83% — D4,
82% — D1,
81% — CF,
**80% —** **CC**,
79% — C9,
78% — C7,
77% — C4,
76% — C2,
75% — BF,
74% — BD,
73% — BA,
72% — B8,
71% — B5,
**70% — B3**,
69% — B0,
68% — **AD**,
67% — AB,
66% — A8,
65% — A6,
64% — A3,
63% — A1,
62% — 9E,
61% — 9C,
**60% —** **99**,
59% — 96,
58% — 94,
57% — 91,
56% — 8F,
55% — 8C,
54% — 8A,
53% — 87,
52% — 85,
51% — 82,
**50% —** **80**,
49% — 7D,
48% — 7A,
47% — 78,
46% — 75,
45% — 73,
44% — 70,
43% — 6E,
42% — 6B,
41% — 69,
**40% —** **66**,
39% — 63,
38% — 61,
37% — 5E,
36% — 5C,
35% — 59,
34% — 57,
33% — 54,
32% — 52,
31% — 4F,
**30% —** **4D**,
29% — 4A,
28% — 47,
27% — 45,
26% — 42,
25% — 40,
24% — 3D,
23% — 3B,
22% — 38,
21% — 36,
**20% — 33**,
19% — 30,
18% — **2E**,
17% — 2B,
16% — 29,
15% — 26,
14% — 24,
13% — 21,
12% — 1F,
11% — 1C,
**10% —** **1A**,
9% — 17,
8% — 14,
7% — 12,
6% — 0F,
5% — 0D,
4% — 0A,
3% — 08,
2% — 05,
1% — 03,
**0% —** **00**
```

Comment: Amazing answer. Keep it up.

Comment: The chart is very handy!

Answer (score 42):

All hex value from 100% to 0% alpha, You can set any color with alpha values mentioned below. e.g #FAFFFFFF(AARRGGBB)

```
100% — FF
99% — FC
98% — FA
97% — F7
96% — F5
95% — F2
94% — F0
93% — ED
92% — EB
91% — E8
90% — E6
89% — E3
88% — E0
87% — DE
86% — DB
85% — D9
84% — D6
83% — D4
82% — D1
81% — CF
80% — CC
79% — C9
78% — C7
77% — C4
76% — C2
75% — BF
74% — BD
73% — BA
72% — B8
71% — B5
70% — B3
69% — B0
68% — AD
67% — AB
66% — A8
65% — A6
64% — A3
63% — A1
62% — 9E
61% — 9C
60% — 99
59% — 96
58% — 94
57% — 91
56% — 8F
55% — 8C
54% — 8A
53% — 87
52% — 85
51% — 82
50% — 80
49% — 7D
48% — 7A
47% — 78
46% — 75
45% — 73
44% — 70
43% — 6E
42% — 6B
41% — 69
40% — 66
39% — 63
38% — 61
37% — 5E
36% — 5C
35% — 59
34% — 57
33% — 54
32% — 52
31% — 4F
30% — 4D
29% — 4A
28% — 47
27% — 45
26% — 42
25% — 40
24% — 3D
23% — 3B
22% — 38
21% — 36
20% — 33
19% — 30
18% — 2E
17% — 2B
16% — 29
15% — 26
14% — 24
13% — 21
12% — 1F
11% — 1C
10% — 1A
9% — 17
8% — 14
7% — 12
6% — 0F
5% — 0D
4% — 0A
3% — 08
2% — 05
1% — 03
0% — 00
```

Answer (score 38):

[image: See screenshot]

I have taken three Views. In the first view I set full (no alpha) color, on the second view I set half (0.5 alpha) color, and on the third view I set light color (0.2 alpha).

You can set any color and get color with alpha by using the below code:

#### File *activity_main.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    android:gravity = "center"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    tools:context = "com.example.temp.MainActivity" >

    <View
        android:id = "@+id/fullColorView"
        android:layout_width = "100dip"
        android:layout_height = "100dip" />

    <View
        android:id = "@+id/halfalphaColorView"
        android:layout_width = "100dip"
        android:layout_height = "100dip"
        android:layout_marginTop = "20dip" />

    <View
        android:id = "@+id/alphaColorView"
        android:layout_width = "100dip"
        android:layout_height = "100dip"
        android:layout_marginTop = "20dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### File *MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private View fullColorView, halfalphaColorView, alphaColorView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fullColorView = (View)findViewById(R.id.fullColorView);
        halfalphaColorView = (View)findViewById(R.id.halfalphaColorView);
        alphaColorView = (View)findViewById(R.id.alphaColorView);

        fullColorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        halfalphaColorView.setBackgroundColor(getColorWithAlpha(Color.BLUE, 0.5f));
        alphaColorView.setBackgroundColor(getColorWithAlpha(Color.BLUE, 0.2f));
    }


    private int getColorWithAlpha(int color, float ratio) {
        int newColor = 0;
        int alpha = Math.round(Color.alpha(color) * ratio);
        int r = Color.red(color);
        int g = Color.green(color);
        int b = Color.blue(color);
        newColor = Color.argb(alpha, r, g, b);
        return newColor;
    }
}
```

**Kotlin version:**

```
private fun getColorWithAlpha(color: Int, ratio: Float): Int {
  return Color.argb(Math.round(Color.alpha(color) * ratio), Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color))
}
```

**Done**

Answer (score 23):

Now **Android Studio 3.3** and later version provide an inbuilt feature to change an **Alpha** value of the color,

Just click on a color in Android studio editor and provide **Alpha value in `percentage`**.

For more information see below image

[image]

Answer (score 19):

There is an XML value `alpha` that takes double values.

Since `API 11+` the range is from `0f` to `1f` (inclusive), `0f` being transparent and `1f` being opaque:

- `android:alpha="0.0"` thats invisible
- `android:alpha="0.5"` see-through
- `android:alpha="1.0"` full visible

That's how it works.

Comment: that will make the whole layout semi-transparent, including it's content

Answer (score 10):

if you want to make color 50% transparent in kotlin,

```
val percentage = 50f/100 //50%
ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(resources.getColor(R.color.whatEverColor), (percentage * 255).toInt())
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        />
```

Alpha ranges between 0(transparent) and 1(opaque) in Android API 11+

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend use `alpha` attribute.

```
<TextView
   android:alpha="0.8" />
```

Or now you can use `selector`. Create `background_color_25.xml` in the `colors` package.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="0.8" android:color="@color/background_color" />
</selector>
```

And here is usages:

```
<TextView
   android:background="@color/background_color_25" />
```

Comment: should be accepted answer imo

Answer (score 5):

See Popularity below textView using this

```
     android:alpha="0.38"
```

[image]

**XML**

```
android:color="#3983BE00"    // Partially transparent sky blue
```

**Dynamically**

**btn.getBackground().setAlpha(128);  // 50% transparent**

**tv_name.getBackground().setAlpha(128);  // 50% transparent**

```
Where the INT ranges from 0 (fully transparent) to 255 (fully opaque).


  <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.38"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="1994|EN" />
```

**android:alpha="0.38"**

```
Text View alpha property set 0.38 to your textView visibility is faid
```

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin,you can use using alpha like this,

```
   //Click on On.//
    view.rel_on.setOnClickListener{
        view.rel_off.alpha= 0.2F
        view.rel_on.alpha= 1F

    }

    //Click on Off.//
    view.rel_off.setOnClickListener {
        view.rel_on.alpha= 0.2F
        view.rel_off.alpha= 1F
    }
```

Result is like in this screen shots.[image: 20 % Transparent]

Hope this will help you.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know, that's a very old question.

If you want use a color value, you can also use the short version of that with `#ARGB`. Where `A` is the value for the alpha channel.

In case of a white color there are the following transparency values:

```
#FFFF  -     0%
#EFFF  -   6,7%
#DFFF  -  13,3%
#CFFF  -  20,0%
#BFFF  -  26,7%
#AFFF  -  33,3%
#9FFF  -  40,0%
#FFF8  -  46,7%
#7FFF  -  53,3%
#6FFF  -  60,0%
#5FFF  -  66,7%
#4FFF  -  73,3%
#3FFF  -  80,0%
#2FFF  -  86,7%
#1FFF  -  93,3%
#0FFF  - 100,0%
```

So you can for `TextView` add the following line for 20% transparency:

```
<TextView
    android:background="#CFFF"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a programmatic solution from [@Aromero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11286013/4370279)'s answer to calculate the hexadecimal value for the alpha channel. :)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int transPerc;
    float fPerc;
    System.out.println("Enter the transparency percentage without % symbol:");
    while((transPerc=scanner.nextInt())>=0 && transPerc <=100){
        fPerc = (float) transPerc / 100;
        transPerc = Math.round(255 * fPerc);
        System.out.println("= " + Integer.toHexString(transPerc));
        System.out.print("another one please : ");
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: The question has been tagged for Android. This code doesn't support Android.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :)**

Its an fully transparent hex code **- "#00000000"**

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you know the color and the opacity, you can get a new color out of both, as such:

```
fun getColorWithAlpha(@ColorInt color: Int, @FloatRange(fromInclusive = true, toInclusive = true, from = 0.0, to = 1.0) opacity: Float): Int {
    val opacityLong =
        (opacity * 255f).roundToLong().coerceIn(0L, 255L) shl (6 * 4) or 0x00ffffff
    val colorLong = color.toLong() or 0xff000000
    return (colorLong and opacityLong).toInt()
}
```