# making the KeyboardView transparent

Tags: android

I am making my own InputMethodService.Everything is working fine.But I have one issue.I want to make the KeyBoard view transparent.That means the keypad view will cover the enter screen & the user can see the whole screen while typing. I tried a lot to make it TRANSPARENT by setting BACKGROUND COLOR,DRAWABLE,but could not success. Please suggest me how to make a custom TRANSPARENT Keypad.
  Does using the method setTheme (int theme) work?

Answer (score 0):

In my configuration setting 
`android:background="@android:color/transparent"` as a property of
`android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView` and using slighltly transparent custom key drawable selector i.e. `android:keyBackground="@drawable/custom_transparent_key"`
 works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your KeyboardView XML file put

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```

Or in your OnCreateInputView set

```
keyboardView.setAlpha((float) 0.5);
```

Reference : [How to make a background 20% transparent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-20-transparent-on-android)