# Android,Transparent Activity programmatically?

Tags: android, android-activity, themes, transparent

I have to create an Activity that is transparent.I can not use resources,so styles.I have to set them transparent programmatically.I use

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_WallpaperSettings);
```

in `onCreate()` method before calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.Docs say:

> public static final int Theme_WallpaperSettings:
>
> Theme for a wallpaper's setting activity, which is designed to be a
>   transparent background with a dark shade, so the previous Activity is
>   visible in the background

But background of Activity is black!It is not transparent.Also I tried these thems:

- _Translucent
- _Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen
- _Dialog

But result is same.Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @blahdiblah I want to create a package and reuse it.If I use resources,I can not add them to package.

Answer (score -5):

You can see this post [Hex transparency in colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors) , or [How to make a background 20% transparent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-transparent-20-in-android)

That posts give you some ways to change color hex code to set transparent color from 0% to 100% and you can apply for all view, not only activity. You can use it in activity by using:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000")); // Add your color code that you want
```