# Tips at start-up or update

Tags: android

I have an update for my app that includes ActionBarSherlock with a sliding menu. I have put my navigation entirely in to the sliding menu, leaving my `main_activity` pretty bare. I am worried the user won't know about the menu. So I want to add a prompt at start-up that will highlight the new feature. Like this:

[image]

I am not even sure what this is called, so I don't know how to research it. Any help or suggestions will be rewarded. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use overlay layout (Frame layout with multiple inner layouts will fit perfectly. Please note Frame Layout Z axis is by the lower the layout is in the xml, so the guide should be the last in the XML). Make that layout's background mostly transparent and add buttons and design to fit your needs. When you don't want to show the layout just set visibility to gone. And when you need it set to visible.

Comment: How do I make background transparent? Just draw a .png?

Comment: Try this: `android:color="#F0F8FF"` About transparacy view this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-transparent-20-in-android