# 50% opacity at white background for textview

Tags: android, background, opacity

I am trying to set  `#ffffff`(white) background at 50% opacity to TextView.
I tried to use `android:alpha=0.5` but it's also making text 50% transparent.

I need to set 50% opacity at white background.
I find one tutorial [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-transparent-20-in-android) but don't understand that much.

Please provide me any reference. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your layout file just set the background of the TextView to "#8FFF"

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="..."
android:layout_height="..."
android:background="#8FFF"
/>
```

Here 8 is the alpha value, FFF are the RGB values respectivley.  [See here for more info on the background attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground)

Comment: but how you calculate this... i didn't get from your link... your answer is right... but need to understand... ow you calculate this?.. Can elaborate?

Comment: These values are hexadecimal values.  Each one you can think of as independent for the A, R, G, B values respectively.  Hex digits are base 16, half of 16 is 8.  Thus the 8.

Comment: then what value for black color at 50% opacity (#0000000)?. I just need to clear for my knowledge.

Comment: Convert the hex values to integer values and divide by 255 to get a percent. So the largest hex value (FF=255) halved would be 80=128, so your whole answer would be #80000000.

Answer (score 4):

In the tutorial that you mention, you will notice that the color value has two digits more that what you are specifying.  You specify #FFFFFF (6 digits), whereas the tutorial specifies #CCFF0000 (8 digits).  The two first digits that were add (CC) represent the alpha.

so in your case try something like #AAFFFFFF

Answer (score 2):

> 50% opacity at teh white background for textview:

```
    <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:alpha=".5"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="50% opacity"
     android:textColor="@color/white" />  

     OR

  <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="50% opacity"
     android:textColor="#80FFFFFF" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you Try:

```
textView.getBackground().setAlpha(range);
```

//Where 0 < range <= 255, 0 being transparent and 255 being opaque