# How to get background color from Android's theme?

Tags: android, colors

I am trying to make the gradient in my activity the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#c0c0c0"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

The bottom part of the gradient should have the same color as the activity and views background. And I quickly realize that `#ffffff` (white) color is not actually background color in my application! I have made the screenshot and discovered that background is actually `#ececec` color.

So is there a way to use current system/theme/style background color in my XML files? I don't want to use hardcoded `#ececec` color because it can be different on other devices and/or Android versions...

Comment: What about using *@android:color/transparent*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these different solutions:

- Transparent color from android resource: `@android:color/transparent`
- Transparent color with hex: `#00000000` (the two first `00` make the opacity to transparent)

For more information about hex opacity color, you should read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11286013/2668136).