# android: how to change the opacity and color gradient of just the background of a text view

Tags: android, gradient, background-color

I need to programatically change the trasparency and color gradient gradually. Let's say I have a textview with background #FF0000FF (solid blue, no transparency) and i need it to change gradually to something that looks like #CC000000 (black background with 80% opacity). Let's say I also have a variable i that gradually goes from 0 to 100, how can I make #FF0000FF transform to #CC000000 along with it?

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-transparent-20-in-android) link for **Setting the transparent background color gradient**

try this code

```
   <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtView"
                            android:layout_width="58dp"
                            android:layout_height="58dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/white_font"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:background="#99000000"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Let's say you have a slider control. As the user slides from A to B, how do you change one color with one transparency to another color with another transparency and gradually?