# relative layout transparent, but i want it opaque

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, transparent

I've a `RelativeLayout` whith the visibility set to `GONE. when I do certain things, the visibility is set to`VISIBLE`and the layout is displayed. The problem is that it should overlap the other contents of the activity, but it's not, I can see the element of the layout but also the activity contents (see the image)

I want the overlapping layout to be opaque.
I've tried to set the backgroud to a color (tried with both ARGB and RGB) and set the alpha (which should be the same as the ARGB) but id doesn't work. any idea?

here is the xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/doc_main_aivalability_panel"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/appBackground">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/doc_main_aivalability_save"
        android:text="salva"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/doc_main_aivalability_list"
        android:layout_above="@id/doc_main_aivalability_save"
        android:background="@color/appBackground"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <CalendarView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/doc_main_availability_calendar"/>
```

the color I am using:

```
<color name="appBackground">#FFF2F2F2</color>
```

and a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you want transparent background? Sorry i couldn't understand your question?

Comment: I recommend use fragments. if not, calendar should have opacitity 100% instead of relativelayout

Comment: you will have to use both the solutions given below by giljulio and imort

Comment: @Vino I wanted the overlapping layout to be opaque!

Comment: @Xenione I know I should use fragments for this, but I don't want to move the existing code for now, maybe in the future ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap RelativeLayout and CalendarView in xml

Because the tree is traversed in-order, this means that parents will be drawn before (i.e., behind) their children, with siblings drawn in the order they appear in the tree.

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html)

Answer (score 1):

The resource called `appBackground` starts with FF and has 8 digits. This means that the color is full transparent. Please refer to this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16890937/973325

To fix it just change it to

```
<color name="appBackground">#F2F2F2</color>
```

Comment: I've already tried to put 00 and also use a RGB color but didn't work. the other answer solved the problem