# Change View Color with alpha animation

Tags: android, android-animation, background-color

I am writing an code where need to modified view background from one color to other color along alpha animation.

I tried with

```
ObjectAnimator backgroundColorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(stickyLayout,
                        "backgroundColor",
                        new ArgbEvaluator(),
                        0xFFFFFFFF,
                        0xff78c5f9);
```

**EDIT:** Since most of us not clear, Assume we need to change this color with alpha on seekbar updated values above mentioned solution work somewhat but not as expected with alpha...any suggestion?

Comment: The colours you are using have full alpha `ff`

Comment: It might be help you: [How to make a background transparent 20% in android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16890937/2668136)

Comment: That is fine ff and Fllo...since I wanted to move from complete white to complete Dark say 0xff78c5f9...any suggestion !

Comment: so if start alpha and end alpha == 0xff, then any values in between will also be 0xff, do you expect other values?

Comment: @pskink I need similar how PlayStore Action bar color get changed on Scroll...any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working code I found so far:

```
    /**
     * Initialise header color while translate animation
     */
    private void initHeaderColor(int startColor, int endColor) {

        initR = Color.red(startColor);
        initG = Color.green(startColor);
        initB = Color.blue(startColor);
        initAlpha = Color.alpha(startColor);

        endR = Color.red(endColor);
        endG = Color.green(endColor);
        endB = Color.blue(endColor);
        endAlpha = Color.alpha(endColor);
    }
```

and set offset of your wish.

```
   /**
     * Translate header view component
     * @param slideOffset
     */
    private void translateHeaderView(float slideOffset) {

            finalR = (int) (initR + (endR - initR) * slideOffset);
            finalG = (int) (initG + (endG - initG) * slideOffset);
            finalB = (int) (initB + (endB - initB) * slideOffset);
            finalAlpha = (int) (initAlpha + (endAlpha - initAlpha) * slideOffset);

            int color = Color.argb(finalAlpha, finalR, finalG, finalB);
            fmActionBar.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

```
ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(**myView**, "backgroundColor", Color.RED, Color.BLUE);
colorAnim.setDuration(3000);
colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
colorAnim.start();
```

Where myView is the view on which you want to apply Animation

Comment: try changing property name to "cardBackgroundColor" instead of "backgroundColor" for CardView

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need these methods: `initHeaderColor` & `translateHeaderView`.

Define an `ArgbEvaluator` as a class member:

```
ArgbEvaluator mArgbEvaluator;

// define start & end colors
int mStartColor, mEndColor;

// initialize start & end colors
```

Call ArgbEvaluator's `evaluate` method with parameters `(slideOffset, startColor, endColor)`, cast the return value to `Integer`, and use it to set the background color of `fmActionBar`:

```
void updateActionBarbgColor(float slideOffset) {
    if (mArgbEvaluator == null)
        mArgbEvaluator = new ArgbEvaluator();

    int bgColor = (Integer) mArgbEvaluator.evaluate(slideOffset, mStartColor, mEndColor);
    fmActionBar.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
}
```

For reference, `ArgbEvaluator#evaluate(...)`:

```
public Object evaluate(float fraction, Object startValue, Object endValue) {
    int startInt = (Integer) startValue;
    int startA = (startInt >> 24) & 0xff;
    int startR = (startInt >> 16) & 0xff;
    int startG = (startInt >> 8) & 0xff;
    int startB = startInt & 0xff;

    int endInt = (Integer) endValue;
    int endA = (endInt >> 24) & 0xff;
    int endR = (endInt >> 16) & 0xff;
    int endG = (endInt >> 8) & 0xff;
    int endB = endInt & 0xff;

    return (int)((startA + (int)(fraction * (endA - startA))) << 24) |
            (int)((startR + (int)(fraction * (endR - startR))) << 16) |
            (int)((startG + (int)(fraction * (endG - startG))) << 8) |
            (int)((startB + (int)(fraction * (endB - startB))));
}
```

Comment: hmm. thought this would fade/ darken colour as i scrolled in onOffsetChanged??

Comment: using it in onOffsetChanged causes a jump between colours not a slow fade?

Comment: @filthy_wizard can you try debugging the code to check the value of `slideOffset`? It should be between 0f & 1f.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Color.parseColor` instead of directly `0x` value. Code example in Kotlin though

```
val objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(my_2_text, "backgroundColor",  ArgbEvaluator(),
    Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#FF78c5f9"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different [evaluator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/blob/master/library/src/com/nineoldandroids/animation/ArgbEvaluator.java) or animate alpha independently with [AnimatorSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html).

Answer (score 0):

I use an static helper Method to interpolate two colors.

```
public static int interpolateColor(int colorA, int colorB, float proportion) {
float[] hsva = new float[3];
float[] hsvb = new float[3];
Color.colorToHSV(colorA, hsva);
Color.colorToHSV(colorB, hsvb);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  hsvb[i] = interpolate(hsva[i], hsvb[i], proportion);
}
int alpha1 = Color.alpha(colorA);
int alpha2 = Color.alpha(colorB);
int newAlpha = interpolate(alpha1, alpha2, proportion);
return Color.HSVToColor(newAlpha, hsvb);  }
```

Also the interpolate Method:

```
private static float interpolate(float a, float b, float proportion) {
return (a + ((b - a) * proportion)); }
```

This method gives the correct color for a proportion value betwenn 0-1 where 0 is colorA is fully visible and 1 means colorB is fully visible.

You then can use a ValueAnimator add an onUpdateListener and get the animationPercentage and pass it as proportion to the interpolate Method.

As you can see i added the alpha values into the method aswell.