# Alpha Value changes makes color become black

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image, android-bitmap

```
    imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
```

I would like to change the alpha value to 10 percent (25) like this.

```
    imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(25, 255, 255, 255));
```

But the color become black rather than transparent white. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agree with **@RRR** you can use this too

define trans_black in color.xml
with code #1A000000

```
ImageView logoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
logoImage.setColorFilter(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.trans_black));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Color.parseColor` and give transparency in hexa code

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#1AFFFFFF"));
```

here first 2 letters `1A` is your transparency code.

for more transparency code check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16890937/3134215)

Comment: This crashes the app.

Answer (score 1):

Set a mode.
`setColorFilter(Color.argb(25, 255, 255, 255),PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);`