# How to make a curved layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

[image]

I am trying to make a layout half transparent what I am trying is to make the red part transparent and the part which is not colored with strong color .I am able to set this with placing a black layer in the back of one layer but I want to make it half transparent like the red part will show the image placed in the back side how can I do this ?
this is the xml I tried

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="0.5dp"
    android:color="@color/white" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="150dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="1000dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
<padding
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp" />

<solid android:color="@color/red"
    />
```

Comment: use radius properties on rectangle. Simple! :)

Comment: @14bce109 can you give an example how to do it ;)

Answer (score 2):

So you have managed that curved shape I guess. To make this transparent, Use its color transparent instead of simple `red` color. Try following code with your xml.

```
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:endColor="#aaF00"
    android:centerColor="#aaF00"
    android:startColor="#aaF00" />
```

So the whole file look like:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="0.5dp"
    android:color="@color/white" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="150dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="1000dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
<padding
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp" />
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:endColor="#aa000000"
    android:centerColor="#aa000000"
    android:startColor="#aa000000" />
/>
```

I've added alpha to your red color. Refer [this link for more information about alpha scale.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-transparent-20-in-android)

You can also visit [this for exact information about colors and especially alpha scale to make color transparent.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors)

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put this shape drawable inside a layer-list drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- black background -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
    <!-- red shape on top of black background -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/curved_shape"/>
</layer-list>
```

Then use this layer-list drawable as your background.

Comment: bro but I am making the red part transparent  so if i place black layer in the back It will not be transparent .How can i make it half transperent

Comment: Ooh.  This isn't really doable with XML.  You would need to code a custom `Drawable` that would draw a `Path` and put different colors inside and outside of the `Path`.

Comment: just combined the concept of @14bce109 and your and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Just place your layout inside one with black background.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="#000000">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/your_shape">
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!" />
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In my real project I am replacing the red part with the transparent so I can not put the background as black