# how to set alpah to a <shape> in xml?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-theme, android-styles, android-shape

I have this @color selector: my_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="0.10" android:color="@color/og_ripple_base_dark" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="@color/og_ripple_base_dark" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.04" android:color="@color/og_ripple_base_dark" android:state_hovered="true"/>
</selector>
```

I want to map it to a @drawable selector

but `<solid>` has no `android:alpha`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:alpha="0.10" android:color="@color/og_ripple_base_light"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:alpha="0.12" android:color="@color/og_ripple_base_light"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_hovered="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <item android:alpha="0.04" android:color="@color/og_ripple_base_light"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

So I have tried this as well, but the alpha channel is ignored when i run on emulator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:color="@color/my_color"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

How can I specify in xml a base color + alpha and set this value to my s tags?

Comment: You can try making a alpha value with the color. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16890937/3964537

Comment: @Megaetron yes, but i would prefer to use strings instead of assembling color codes. possible?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no other way than using color codes. Except you give an alpha value the view which receives the shape.