# My own AppcompatDialog generates a really ugly shadow/elevation

Tags: java, android, customdialog

I tried to create my own custom loading dialog on android. That was no problem, but the dialog creates a really ugly shadow when it appears

I tried to use a default color theming my android and not my own. And i tried to set a transparent windows background and set the elevation already to 0dp

Screenshot
[enter link description here](https://ibb.co/9w9n8Yz)

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <!--<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark.Loading.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

dialog-layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark.Loading.Dialog"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_loading_dialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Authenticating..."
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar_loading_dailog"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_view_loading_dialog"


            android:indeterminate="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Dialogclass

```
public class LoadingDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    private TextView messageTextView;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(view);
        messageTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_loading_dialog);


        return builder.create();
    }
```

Activity

```
 LoadingDialog loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog();
loadingDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "loading dialog");
```

I expected a normal black or light grey shadow, like the depracted ProgressDialog by Google

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, add the `clearFlags()` method, like this:

```
LoadingDialog loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog();
loadingDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
loadingDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "loading dialog");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that helps! Thank you very much. But removing this flag, remoes the whole dimming background. I build a workaround with a invisible dimmed View on my activity, which i make visible everytime my dialog pops up.

I added that to my activity layout

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/dimBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorDimBackground"
    android:visibility="invisible">

</View>
```

My color is this:

```
<color name="colorDimBackground">#B3000000</color>
```

The #B3 is the hexcode for 70% opacity. You can find the a table with all hex values here:

[Hex values for opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-20-transparent-on-android)

And before a I show the dialog, i make the view visible

```
findViewById(R.id.dimBackground).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    LoadingDialog loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog();
    loadingDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "loading dialog");
```

Maybe there is a more practical solution for this problem, but i have no idea!?

This is the result:

[image: Final Screenshot]