# How purple 200/500/700 define in the color.xml of a new Android Project?

Tags: android, colors, color-palette

In a new Android project, it provides a set of purple color for colorPrimary etc. I am interested in how the default color code is generated from.

Android default colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

On the other hand, I found a [color tool](https://material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0) in material.io that have provided

purple 200 = #ce93d8

purple 500 = #9c27b0

purple 700 = #7b1fa2

which does not match the android default purple color. Is it because it has used a different "purple"? or it changed the opacity?

Comment: One is `ARGB` and Other one is `RGB` hex code . A in `ARGB` represent alpha i.e opacity (first two chars).  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39128318/4168607) are opacity value check for yourself .

Comment: Both use 100% opacity, so it is not opacity. It is just that "purple" is not a well defined colour, and material prefer in general saturated colours (on the other hand, your purple_500 and purple_700 (on the code) seems not really purple (it seems they just selected one purple, and keep the hue angle, also if the result is no more purple)