# softkeyboard overlay

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

Does anyone know how to add an overlay panel/layout over a keyboard. I've trying several ways using the Sample softkeyboard without much success. Have been reading and trying to apply these:

-[Overlay an activity on another activity OR overlay a view over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878235/overlay-an-activity-on-another-activity-or-overlay-a-view-over-another)

-[Android overlay a view ontop of everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519160/android-overlay-a-view-ontop-of-everything)

-[Android - Dynamically Add Views into View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view)

I suppose that these work when implementing an activity rather than a service such as a keyboard.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Put your layout inside scrolllistciew and then use 
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" in your activity manifest               declaration